Why doesn't std::array's operator[] retain the value category of the array?
I'd have expected that if an std::array is an rvalue, then calling operator[] returns an rvalue as well. But it doesn't seem to be the case (cppreference), there are no value-category overloads.
For example, std::optional respects the value category (cppreference). Why don't we have the same overloads in std::array, like this?
const T &&operator[](size_type pos) const &&
const T &operator[](size_type pos) const &
T &&operator[](size_type pos) &&
T &operator[](size_type pos) &

(of course, this question is not just about operator[], but all the other accessor functions)

Here's is an example which shows that in this regard, std::array is not a drop-in replacement for old-style arrays. With old-style arrays, the result of the index operator is an rvalue reference, but with std::array, it is not:
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    int old_way[1];
    std::array<int, 1> new_way;

    printf("old_way, is_rvalue_reference: %d\n", std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(std::move(old_way)[0])>);
    printf("new_way, is_rvalue_reference: %d\n", std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(std::move(new_way)[0])>);
}

This program prints:
old_way, is_rvalue_reference: 1
new_way, is_rvalue_reference: 0


Consider void foo(T,T); called via a rvalue array foo(arr[0],arr[0]). This would break.  std::optional is different because it models a single value (that can be present or not), it is more obvious that once you move from it, it is in a moved from state.

This feels like there's an underlying problem you try to solve. It's fine if it's plain curiosity, but no matter what please tell us about the underlying problem (or state that it's just a curiosity thing).

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: what is arr in your example? If it is a variable, then it is an lvalue.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai In foo(arr[0],arr[0]), arr[0] is an lvalue.  You would have to use foo(std::move(arr[0]), std::move(arr[0]))

Do you want the operator[] to behave in a way inconsistent with iterators, or do you want arr.begin() to return a different iterator type from std::move(arr).begin()(which can no longer be a plain pointer)? It feels strange either way. This is a common issue to all standard library containers.

@Someprogrammerdude: there is no underlying problem, this is a purely design question.

@WeijunZhou: I'm not sure regarding the interactions with iterators. Still, if x is an rvalue, then x.member is an rvalue as well. This concept is broken for std::array. If x is an rvalue, x[0] is still an lvalue. But both return a subobject of an rvalue, so both expressions should be an rvalue. The current behavior is inconsistent if we look at it from this perspective.

std::array and other existing sequential containers predate the notion of rvalues. I suspect making operator[] &&  return an rvalue reference might change the behaviour of existing code.

So mostly history, if it would be done without the history and retro-compatibility concern, those methods would probably be rvalue qualified.

It behaves consistently with other (sequence) containers. The (sequence) container concept requires the type to have member typedefs reference and const_reference which shall be returned by operator[] depending on const-qualification. But there is no equivalent distinction made for lvalue and rvalue references to elements.
Containers have existed before C++11 when the reference qualifiers for member functions were introduced. So they were not able to forward value category originally. And because of a lack of move semantics it wouldn't have been very helpful at that time either.
Also, std::array was originally part of TR1 and derived from boost::array, both before C++11. At the time the necessary syntax didn't exist yet either.
